# Error in Restoring backup to secondary database using log shipping

Tags: sql-server, database, log-shipping

I'm trying log shipping between two SQL VMs. The backup is getting generated properly but its not getting restore on secondary database. The error says that the restore job is not able to open the .bak file of the  database.

Below are the error details:

```
TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
------------------------------

SQL Server Management Studio restore database 'TestDB1'

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (SqlManagerUI)

------------------------------

Cannot open backup device '\\vm-p\NetworksharepathTlogs\TestDB1.bak'. Operating system error 5(Access is denied.).
RESTORE FILELIST is terminating abnormally. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 3201)
```

There were 3 sections when configuring log shipping so the first step that was primary backup setting was successful. And backup got generated in the folder. I have given full control to the users involves read, write ,etc. But still my log shipping is failing coz of this error.

In second step of log shipping two actions were performed one was restoring database to secondary server and other is saving secondary destination configuration . So I separately run the jobs and found that restoring database to secondary is causing an issue. This error is thrown on that step failure.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error message says "access is denied" which means the account running the SQL service on the target instance doesn't have permission to read the backup file.

Comment: The backup job is able to generate jobs in that folder. And I have given rights to user, sql service account and admin full control, @BenThul.

Comment: And yet you're still getting an error. You're using a network share, so the permissions of the share apply. Do they permit reading files in that location?

Comment: Yes. There were 3 sections when configuring log shipping so the first step that is primary backup setting was successful. And backup got generated in the folder. I have given full control to the users involves read right,etc. But still my log shipping is failing coz of this error.

Comment: In second step of log shipping two actions are performed one is restoring database to secondary server and other is saving secondary destination configuration . So I separately run the jobs and found that restoring database to secondary is causing an issue. This error is thrown on that step failure, @BenThul. Please Help!

Comment: Please verify the following: When you go into the properties of Log Shipping there is a "Copy Files" tab that has a place for you to specify a directory. This entry is what the restore job uses to try to restore transaction log backups, even if you disable the Copy jobs.  If the path is slightly misspelled or wrong, the restore jobs will fail and can seem to be running into permissions issues when really it's because the directory does not exist.